# Populating a ListView with firebase data

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to populate my ListView but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm able to print the values and also toast then they just wont populate my ListView. Is there anyone that can help me populate it?

MainActivity

```
package uk.co.jaunt_app.jaunt;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers;
import com.crashlytics.android.answers.CustomEvent;
import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import static uk.co.jaunt_app.jaunt.R.id.Posts;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private FloatingActionButton addmap;
    private Button settingbtn;
    private TextView mNameTextView;
    private TextView mEmailTextView;
    ListView mPosts;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.jauntlogodark);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Posts);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

        Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);
        FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        String uid = currentFirebaseUser.getUid();
        Firebase usersRef = ref.child("Users").child(uid).child("name");
        Firebase emailRef = ref.child("Users").child(uid).child("email");
        Firebase postRef = ref.child("Users").child(uid).child("Maps");

        mNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NameTextView);
        mPosts = (ListView) findViewById(Posts);


        postRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (final DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //Getting the data from snapshot

                    Person person = postSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);
                    String posts = "Name: " + person.getMapName() + "\n\n";


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Name: " + person.getMapName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();

                    mPosts.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });


        mEmailTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EmailTextView);

        emailRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String email = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mEmailTextView.setText(email);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });



        addmap = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add_map);
        addmap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent("Added Map"));
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapStartActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        settingbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settingbtn);
        settingbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Move this

```
mPosts.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To here

```
mPosts = (ListView) findViewById(Posts);
mPosts.setAdapter(adapter);
```

2) Do this to actually get data displayed

```
String mapName = person.getMapName();
adapter.add(mapName);
```

3) Replace

```
android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line
```

With

```
android.R.layout.android simple_list_item_1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

add your adapter to your listview

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.jauntlogodark);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Posts);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);
    FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    String uid = currentFirebaseUser.getUid();
    Firebase usersRef = ref.child("Users").child(uid).child("name");
    Firebase emailRef = ref.child("Users").child(uid).child("email");
    Firebase postRef = ref.child("Users").child(uid).child("Maps");

    mNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NameTextView);
    mPosts = (ListView) findViewById(Posts);
    mPosts.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Data also needs added to the adapter